# Xcode storyboard Emoji & Symbols display incorrectly

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am trying to add an Button on the storyboard with a greek letter Pi as its title. I navigate to **Edit -> Emoji&Symbols**, double click on a Pi to add it. So far so good. But once I clicked on any other places on the storyboard, this Pi turns into a question mark in a box. I try to google it but I can't find anything(I think part of the reason is because I don't know how to phrase this question concisely). Any help would be appreciated!